# Add/remove items from state when working with multiple checkboxes not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, use-state

I have a list of checkboxes and when one it selected, I want the associated ID to be added to a state object and when its unchecked, the ID should be removed from the state object.

Currently, the state object only updates when a second checkbox is selected (and state only contains the first checkbox) -- aka its always 1 checkbox behind. Its then the opposite when unchecking -- if 3 boxes are checked, state shows 4 boxes selected.

I'm a super new dev so I'm sure this is incredibly simple, any help would be much appreciated :)

```
const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState(new Array(20).fill(false));
const [checkedPlaylists, setCheckedPlaylists] = useState({});

const handleChange = (position, id) => {
  const updatedCheckedState = checkedState.map((item, index) =>
    index === position ? !item : item
  );

  setCheckedState(updatedCheckedState);

  if (checkedState[position] === false) {
    setCheckedPlaylists(prev => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [position]: id
      }
    })
  } else {
    setCheckedPlaylists(prev => {
      delete checkedPlaylists[position]
      return { ...prev }
    })
  }
}
```

Here's the jsx

```
return (
<>
  <h3>Select Playlists</h3>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <ul className='playlists-list' style={{"listStyle": "none"}}>
      {playlists?.items.map((playlist, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            <div className='playlists-list-item'>
              <input 
                type='checkbox'
                id={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}
                name={playlist.name}
                value={playlist.name}
                checked={checkedState[index]}
                onChange={() => handleChange(index, playlist.id)}
              />
              <label htmlFor={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}>{playlist.name}</label>
            </div>
          </li>
        )
      })}
    </ul>
    <div>
      <button className='submit-btn' type='submit'>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <TopSongs playlists={playlists} />
</>
```

)

Comment: You can't access updated state in the same render cycle. Either use `updatedCheckedState` for your further conditional actions, or use a `useEffect` dependent on `checkedState`.

Comment: Ah of course! Thanks so much